# Unable to find Microsoft.XNA.Framework.dll with dll copied local

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dll, xna, xna-4.0

I have a project where I am using the Microsoft XNA framework for sound rendering.  It works fine on my PC, but when I deploy the project to the client computer, it states that it can't find Microsoft.XNA.Framework.dll.  I have the Copy Local attribute setup to copy this dll into into my project, due to the client computer not having XNA installed.

The client computer is not connected to the internet and at this time, cannot be connected to the internet.

The client computer is a Windows XP PC.  My development computer has the XNA framework installed and is a Windows 7 PC.

Due to project concerns, we would like to not have to install the entire XNA framework, due to the intensive nature of some of the software on the client PC's and only want to have the base components needed for my program to run.

Is there any other dll's that Microsoft.XNA.Framework.dll is dependent on, or will it just not work without the full XNA framework being installed?

Thanks

Comment: did you see that the dll file has indeed passed to the client's computer?

Comment: Yes, I have it packaged in an MSI and I verified the install

Comment: are you loading the dll using reflection? can you check from where are you loading it? if you don't know how tell me and i'll post it as an answer, it's a bit long

Comment: I just have it as a reference within my project.  I'm debating using reflection to load it.

Comment: The DLL is in the same folder as the executable?

Comment: It was.  We just decided to go ahead and install the XNA framework re-distributable on the client PC and tested it against our other software to ensure it didn't impact performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was decided to go ahead and install the re-distributable version of the XNA framework on the client PC and evaluate the performance so that continued development time would not be necessary.

If an issue occurs, this issue will be re-evaluated then.

Thanks